# Nuxt.js router - change route params without re-mounting a new page?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a single-page app with Nuxt.js (v 2.15.7) that needs to get two parameters from the URL. For example:

```
domain.com 
domain.com/chapter3
domain.com/chapter3/section5
```

All 3 of these addresses should render the same page found in `pages/index.vue`, I just want to be able to read the `$route.params.chapterNo` and `$route.params.sectionNo` as it changes, without really redirecting to a different page.

I've partially accomplished this by editing [my `nuxt.config.js` file](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#extendroutes) as follows:

```js
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
      name: 'chapter',
      path: '/chapter:chapterNo?',
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/index.vue')
    });
    routes.push({
      name: 'section',
      path: '/chapter:chapterNo?/section:sectionNo?',
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/index.vue')
    });
  }
},
```

The only problem is that this destroys the previous version of `pages/index.vue` and re-mounts a new version of it each time you route to a new chapter or section. `mounted()` gets called on each route change, but I need the page to be mounted only once. It's going to be animated as the address changes, but with this setup, the whole DOM gets cleared and re-built, removing the possibility for animations. What router config can I use to only get the two params without re-rendering the whole page?

I've tried removing the `component` property of the config file, but that gives me `page not found` errors.

#### Attempt 1:

I tried using `keep-alive` on the root `<Nuxt>` component, but this only caches each page. It still gets re-mounted once on each route change.

#### Attempt 2:

I tried the `router-extras` module with the [define multiple parameters](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module#define-multiple-params-regardless-of-pages-directory-structure) option, but that also re-mounts `pages/index.vue` each time the route changes. This is my attempt, which yields the same issue:

```
<router>
{
    path: '/chapter:chapterNo?/mission:missionNo?',
}
</router>
```

Is there any way to change routes to get the parameters without re-mounting `pages.index.vue`?

Comment: What if you try to add aliases with this package? https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module#define-multiple-aliases-for-single-page

Comment: I see a solution to this. Meanwhile I'm wondering if this could not be solved with query params, rather than path variables.

Comment: @kissu Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried using `router-extras` with the multiple parameters option, but it still does the same re-mounting of `pages/index.vue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the Vue developer tools with `<Nuxt keep-alive />` in my default layouts file, and noticed that Nuxt was creating a new instance of `pages/index.vue` with a unique key for each chapter and section:

[image]

This gave me the idea to forcefully assign a constant key to the page by using

`<Nuxt nuxt-child-key="doNotReMount"/>`.

[image]

Now that the key doesn't update on each new route, the `pages/index.vue` page is only mounted once, and all subsequent routes use the same instance of this page!

Answer (score 2):

To cache the rendered component, use [`keep-alive`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#keep-alive) on the `<Nuxt>` component in the layout:

```html
<Nuxt keep-alive />
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-keep-page-alive?file=layouts/default.vue)

To only cache that specific page, use `keep-alive-props.include` with the component name (which is the path for pages):

```html
<Nuxt keep-alive
      :keep-alive-props="{ include: 'pages/index.vue' }"
/>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-keep-page-alive-fweyhr?file=layouts%2Fdefault.vue)

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I tried it on my build, and on your demo, but it looks like the page is re-built, and `mounted()` is still called each time the route changes. See here: https://i.imgur.com/GrrCZ3s.jpg I added a `console.log("Hello")` on mounted(), and it gets triggered 3 times. Once it has visited `/chapter5`, `chapter5/section3` and `/` for the first time, it finally stops getting triggered on subsequent visits. It seems like `keep-alive` re-renders the first time you arrive at each address, and then remembers each subsequent visit.

Comment: @Marquizzo `keep-alike` keeps it cached indeed. But changes down the road still needs to get triggered IMO.

Comment: @kissu Yes, it looks like `keep-alive` is not the solution I'm looking for. I'm trying to just capture the new router parameters without re-rendering the page at all.

Comment: @Marquizzo The reason it mounts 3 different times is because you have 3 different routes with the same component (the page): One is automatically scaffolded from the directory based routing, and two others are from `extendRoute` in `nuxt.config.js`.

Comment: @tony19 Thank you, I understand why it does it. `keep-alive` caches the component without destroying it, but it still re-mounts a new version of the page the first time you land on each possible route. With 6 chapters and 10 sections, that's 60 times the page will mount. I'm trying to mount it only once.